# I want to get all venues where list of amenities belongs to that venue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, associations

I really don't have an Idea how to query to get all the specific venues where list of amenities check by the user belongs to that venues.

Example. I have a list of checkbox where the amenities displayed and If I check the swimming pool, billiard pool, gym, and disco house It will display the list of venue that belongs to that amenities.

My association is like this:

Model

```
venue
categorization
amenity
```

Association

```
Venue.rb

has_many :categorizations
has_many :amenities, through: :categorizations

Amenity.rb

has_many :categorizations
has_many :venues, through: :categorizations

Categorization.rb

belongs_to :venue
belongs_to :amenity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple amenities and want to find all venues, you can do this:

```
selected_amenity_ids = [1,2,3]
@venues = Venue.joins(:amenities).where(:amenities => {:id => selected_amenity_ids})
```

This will result in one single SQL query with two INNER JOINS.

Comment: I forgot to closed it. I already get it last 2 days. by the way thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@amenity = Amenity.find(id)
@venues = @amenity.venues
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how to get that but what if I check many amenities?

Comment: It will pass the array of ids and find accordingly

Comment: Thank you sir. Can you give an example?